# how to read .txt file which is in static resource

Tags: static-resources

I have Account.txt file to create Account records from Static Resource,how can i read Account.txt file in visualforce page?

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:form >
  <apex:commandButton value="Get Data From Txt"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and I have data in the Account.txt as below:

> sobject-'Account' Name='ram' Name='hari'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solution could be you can query on Static Resource object and get the body of that resource and then Process logic accordingly.

```
StaticResource srObject = [select id,body from StaticResource Where Name = 'SOME RESOURCE NAME'];
String contents = srObject.body.toString();
for(String line:contents.split('\n')) {
  // Process Logic Here
}
```

You can also check this useful [blog](https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/access-static-resources-from-apex-visualforce-and-custom-button/)

Comment: 1:53:01.0 (52364002)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|contents sobject-'Account'
Name='ram'
Name='hari'
11:53:01.0 (523862,,how can i pull out Sobject and Name colum,,can u please tel me how to do it,,

Comment: i had gone gone through your blog,still i didnot get an idea how to create Account records from Account.txt file

Comment: if u can help how to create records using getting the object name from the .txt  will be very help full for me